# Show a page inside a Page in windows phone app

Tags: windows-phone-8

Is it possible to show a PhoneApplicationPage inside another PhoneApplication page.
For example if i loaded page1 of the application using the below code from HomePage.xaml

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Page1.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
```

And i want to show a new page say Page2.xaml , i can Navigate to this page using the same above code , but i dont want to open it as a seperate page , but rather wants to Open the Page2.xaml inside Page1.xaml itself as either popup or some other way , so when user closes Page2 it will show the Page1 in the state

Comment: Why do you want to show a page in a page? Can you give some use cases. There might be other ways to solve your problem

Comment: For managing the code easily . Keeping all specific functionality in a page and i dont want to  mix all things together . But not sure its  a good idea or not.
Example : My page1.xaml uses some settings value , so i keep a page2 for saving and editting all settings values and in page1 i am just using all those settings values

Comment: You should create a SettingsPage.xaml and navigate to it. Use the framework already laid out rather than creating one yourself

Comment: At present i am doing this . Navigating to Settings.xaml , but i want to show the page in same view itself

Comment: Continue to do this. It is the best solution. If you're looking for page transitions check out [this blog](http://www.visuallylocated.com/post/2013/12/15/Creating-simple-page-transitions-using-Storyboards-Slide-transition.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you use a UserControl instead of a Page, you can turn its visibility on/off (instead of navigating).

Answer (score 0):

No you can't like Igor Kulman said. But you can bind all the content and change page as you want with new data.(Title / Content / grid / all :) )

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can not declare 2 PhoneApplicationPage tags in a single page. Still you could try some tricks  .

You can make the dummy of a PhoneApplicationPage Like this

if this is your layoutRoot

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
 </Grid>
```

then you can make 2 pages in a single layoutroot tag and control their Visibility accordingly.
Just remove the row definitions and put two stackpanels. Now these stackpanels spans over the complete grid.

Something like this helps

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
<StackPanel Name="Page1" Background="Red" Visibility="Visible"/>
<StackPanel Name="Page2" Background="Black" Visibility="Collapsed"/> 
</Grid>
```

Below are the two images which describes your solution better.

Making the first stackpanel Visible

[image]

Making the Second stackpanel Visible

[image]

Hope it Helps

Comment: The idea is correct, but what i am trying to do is to manage the code easily . Keeping all specific functionality in a page and i dont want to mix all things together . But not sure its a good idea or not. Example : My page1.xaml uses some settings value , so i keep a page2 for saving and editting all settings values and in page1 i am just using all those settings values , so the page1 code is always specific to page1 only

Comment: If you are looking to keep your code clean and managed, Then I would suggest you to use a usercontrol instead. Or, if you find easy to use the same screen to save and display the data. Then u can easily use the way I recommended.